How to Dynamically Retrieve ACF Boolean Value in WPBakery Grid template / shortcode?
Setup:

WordPress Plugins: WPBakery

Theme: Highend with child theme


Approach So Far:

Added ACF Field: Successfully added a custom field using Advanced Custom Fields (ACF) and verified the values in the postmeta table.

Identified Template File: Found the file responsible for the HTML output (vc-gitem-zone.php) in the child theme and confirmed modifications reflected on the site.


Goal:
Retrieve the ACF field value (is_lent) in the template file to conditionally render styles.
Code Snippet & Challenges:
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    die( '-1' );
}
/**
 * Shortcode attributes
 * @var $atts
 * @var $el_class
 * @var $css
 * @var $position
 * @var $bgimage
 * @var $height
 * @var $link
 * @var $url
 * @var $height_mode
 * @var $featured_image
 * @var $img_size
 * @var $render
 * @var $content - shortcode content
 * Shortcode class
 * @var WPBakeryShortCode_Vc_Gitem_Zone $this
 */
$el_class = $css = $position = $bgimage = $height = $link = $url = $height_mode = $featured_image = $img_size = $render = $rel = '';

$css_style = $css_style_mini = '';
$image_block = $image = '';

$atts = vc_map_get_attributes( $this->getShortcode(), $atts );
extract( $atts );


// TASK either retrieve post_id or acf "is_lent" for this post


// Retrieve current post ID
global $post;
$post_id = $post->ID;

// Retrieve ACF field value
$lent = get_field("is_lent", $post_id);
echo 'ACF is: ' . $lent;

//NOTHING Is being retrieved.


if (empty($lent)) {
    echo "<script>console.log('ACF field \"is_lent\" is empty or not defined for post ID: " . $post_id . "');</script>";
} else {
  echo "<script>console.log('ACF field \"is_lent\": " . json_encode($lent) . "');</script>";
};

if ( 'no' === $render ) {
    return '';
}
// Code for updating the css and assembling the html....


$output = '';
$output .= '<div class="' . esc_attr( $css_class ) . '"';
$output .= ( empty( $css_style ) ? '' : ' style="' . esc_attr( $css_style ) . '"' );
$output .= '>';
$output .= $image_block . $image;
$output .= '<div class="' . esc_attr( $css_class_mini ) . '"' . ( empty( $css_style_mini ) ? '' : ' style="' . esc_attr( $css_style_mini ) . '"' ) . '>' . do_shortcode( $content ) . '</div></div>';

echo $output;

Attempts Made:

I tried retrieving via post ID (it worked when hardcoded, but I couldn't get it dynamically).

Utilized attachment_url_to_postid() (worked when hardcoded URL, but couldn't dynamically retrieve the URL).

I tried [acf field="is_lent"] shortcode, but it didn't yield results.


Expected Outcome:
Dynamically retrieve the ACF bool value.
Actual Outcome:
Unable to dynamically retrieve the post ID or ACF value, hindering the conditional rendering.
Request:
Seeking guidance or suggestions on how to achieve dynamic retrieval of ACF value in the template file. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

to retrieve the dynamic  ACF value you should read the wpBakery documentation. They explain it in how to "Adding Custom Shortcode to Grid Builder". I hope it will help you to fulfill your requirements.

Thank you @GS_ found my solution there :)
